# how to do normalization if I got a test set (5000, 784) but the test label (2000,)

Tags: python

Given a training data (30000, 784) training label(30000,)
a test data (5000, 784) but the test label (2000,)
3000 of the test label is not given,
how to do normalization to fit knn in this case.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10)

knn.fit(data_train_norm, label_train)

knn_label_pred = knn.predict(data_test_norm)
```

Error

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [30000, 5000]
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO :) Test data is the one we only face in the field so there is no necessity for the presence of it, if your solution relies on test labels to do something it is a red flag for data leakage! adding full code can make it easier for the community to help you out!

Comment: You have to sub-select for only the part of the data you have labels for; just take `test_data[:2000]` to get it to (2000, 784) shape

Comment: Afaik normalization of input features should've nothing to do with the labels. In any case, you can compute your normalization statistics (e.g. mean & std.dev. for z-score normalization) on the train data and apply the normalization with help of these statistics on your test data.